# How many subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ have the property that there are at least two elements and the sum of the two largest elements is 13?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am not sure how to start but I think I need to consider the amount of subsets where there are 2 elements, 3 elements, and 4 elements ... separately. How do I start?

Comment: There are only 3 cases: 9+4=7+6=8+5. Then you can count the subset. For example with the set contains 9 and 4, number of the subsets is number of subset of 0,1,2,3, which is 2^4. And so on.

Comment: what do you mean by 9+4=7+6=8+5?

Comment: Each of those sums to $13$.  Having two equals signs just means that all three expressions are equal.

Comment: The answer would be $2^6+2^5+2^4$ I guess

Comment: @user600016 why is it 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4?

Comment: Is the answer correct?

Comment: For case 9+4, you can have the elements {0,1,2,3} in addition to them only. Similar for other cases

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion:

Start by choosing the two elements that will sum to $13$, say $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$. These will be the largest two elements of the set.  Then you can also include (or not) any elements that are less than $a$.

For instance if you take $8$ and $5$ initially, you can then include any subset of the elements $4,3,2,1,0$.

Comment: how do I count the number of ways to have the sets? for example {8,5}, {8, 5, 0}, {8, 5, 2, 3}... How do I count how many of those there are?